# The apk file made with buildozer does not start

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, apk, buildozer

Converting the main file.py in the apk using buildozer is successful, but for some reason my file does not run on the phone.
Here is my import:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import string
import httplib2
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import itertools
import random
from pyaspeller import YandexSpeller
import threading
```

As I read on the forums, the problem may be in beautifulsoup but I do not know how to solve this problem, please help me!

Here is my log:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyyXO.jpg)

Comment: could post the logcat...

Comment: I added my log above

Comment: Could you also post the `buildozer.spec` ?